# How to convert inline assembly in msbuild to gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, inline-assembly

My code which uses inline assembly is executes complatly in visual studio 2019.

I want to execute this code in GCC enviroment. But, I don`t have any idea to do

How can I do that?

this is my code

```
int a, b;
cin >> a >> b;
__asm {
    cmp b, 30;
    jl bunder30;
    jge bup30;

bunder30 :
    add a, - 1;
    add b, 60;
bup30 :
    add b, - 30;
    
    cmp a, 0;
    jge endPtr;
    add a, 24;

    endPtr :
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline assembler is standardized in C++, so try to follow the C++ standard ([see this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/asm)) instead of using non-standard extensions. That is, use this syntax:

> **asm (** *string_literal* **) ;**

[GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html) for details and alternative (non-standard) ways.